# Prevent multiple clicks until animation is done (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have a gallery with thumbnails and when the thumbnails are clicked the current image fades out and the new image fades in.

However, I want to stop multiple clicks, so the image has to fade out completely before being able to click a new thumbnail.

How can I do this with the code below?

Many thanks,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>TEST</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>

<style type='text/css'>
#imageWrap{
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
height:534px;
width:800px;
}
.next{
display:none;
}
#imageWrap img{
width: 800px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #000;
}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('.thumbnail').on('click',function(){
$('#imageWrap').append('<img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" class="next" />');
$('#imageWrap .active').fadeOut(5500);
$('#imageWrap .next').fadeIn(4000, function(){
    $('#imageWrap .active').remove();
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

});
});//]]>  

</script>

</head>
<body>
<img src="dimming/1.jpg" class="thumbnail" alt="A" width="40" height="40"/>
<img src="dimming/2.jpg" class="thumbnail" alt="B" width="40" height="40"/>
<img src="dimming/C.jpg" class="thumbnail" alt="C" width="40" height="40"/>
<img src="dimming/D.jpg" class="thumbnail"alt="D" width="40" height="40"/>
<img src="dimming/E.jpg" class="thumbnail" alt="E" width="40" height="40"/>

<div id="imageWrap">
    <img src="dimming/C.jpg" alt="Main Image" width="800" height="534" class="active" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually do this in a really simple way. On click I add a div to the image container, which is positioned absolutely inside the container. And when all animations are done, I just remove this layer. It can be done in a number of ways actually, but this way I don't have to bother with removing/adding listeners.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304883/disable-until-animation-complete

Comment: Eduard, do you have an example of this, sounds interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding a boolean flag whose status you can check before deciding what to do:

```
// Are we in the middle of an animation?
var currentlyAnimating = false;

$('.thumbnail').on('click',function(){
    if (currentlyAnimating) {
        return;
    }

    currentlyAnimating = true;

    $('#imageWrap').append('...');
    $('#imageWrap .active').fadeOut(5500);
    $('#imageWrap .next').fadeIn(4000, function(){
        $('#imageWrap .active').remove();
        $(this).addClass('active');
        currentlyAnimating = false;
    });
});
```

Of course you can also make this check by querying the status of the DOM or jQuery's effects queue for the elements in question, but IMO it is much simpler and cleaner with a localized solution like the above.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, the image faded out and the next one doesn't fade in.

I used:

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
var currentlyAnimating = false;

$('.thumbnail').on('click',function(){
    if (currentlyAnimating) {
        return;
    }

    currentlyAnimating = true;

    $('#imageWrap').append('...');
    $('#imageWrap .active').fadeOut(5500);
    $('#imageWrap .next').fadeIn(4000, function(){
        $('#imageWrap .active').remove();
        $(this).addClass('active');
        currentlyAnimating = false;
    });
});
});

</script>

Comment: @DarrenRiches: That has to be an unrelated problem with the code which you have to debug. Providing a working example we can view on http://jsfiddle.com would help.

Comment: Hi Jon, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/darrenriches/696dN/ - Appreciate your help.

Comment: @DarrenRiches: Uh, that `.append('...')` is a placeholder really. Replace with your actual code. :)

Comment: Oh dear, I am stupid, can't believe I didn't notice that! Thanks for you help. Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

You can check that `#imageWrap .next` and `#imageWrap .active` are not animated using the `:animated` selector.

```
$('.thumbnail').on('click',function(){
   if(!$("#imageWrap .next, #imageWrap .active").is(":animated")){
      $('#imageWrap').append('<img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" class="next" />');
      $('#imageWrap .active').fadeOut(5500);
      $('#imageWrap .next').fadeIn(4000, function(){
          $('#imageWrap .active').remove();
          $(this).addClass('active');
      });//this was missing      
   }
});
```

Comment: That codes up with a syntax error on: line:    if(!$("#imageWrap .next, #imageWrap .active").is(":animated"){   am I doing something stupid?

Comment: @DarrenRiches Thanks for pointing that out, I was missing a `)` on the if statement.  Updated code should work

Comment: Ah yes, that's solved the error on that line, but then it's got a syntax error on the last }); now.