# jQuery custom function animation queueing up on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

What is meant to happen is a stack of div's rotate every 10sec by default.

Issue is when the user clicks a button that triggers the same animation the delay of the animation is ignored and each div fade-in and out repeatedly how do I stop this from happening.

```
//Quotes rotation
    var quotes = $(".quote");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {

        $('.quote').css({
            'display' : 'none'
        });

        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(500)
            .delay(10000)
            .fadeOut(500, showNextQuote);
    }

    //Initialize the rotation
    showNextQuote();

    $('.paginate').on('click', function() {
        showNextQuote();
    });
```

Comment: you can control the animation by checking the progress bit , like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304883/disable-until-animation-complete

Comment: Also when I look in the console every time the button is clicked this error message appears "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: I dont get it, when there is continuous fading in and fading out happening , why would you need to click the button which inturn triggers same function. its like one chain already running and button click has created second chain , hence the delay is not noticeable and the result is continuous flickering

Comment: Its a stupid feature request from the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
$('.quote').css({
    'display' : 'none'
});
```

for

```
$('.quote').stop(true).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also disable click event effect when this is already animating.
It depends on your needs and the context.